# Question about Linear Transform

Tags: linear-algebra

We transform
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
 + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and the equation
$$
x^2+16xy+14y^2-30x-40y=0
$$

[image]

Can I ask a dumb question? It basically says there is a new coordinate , and the following equation can be written by the new variables. I tried to use the quadratic form to represent the equation but after that, I have no clue :(

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I don't really read Chinese, unfortunately. You may fare a little better if you replace the image with translation of the actual problem. Can you explain what is the relationship between the transformation mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (x',y')$ and the quadratic equation? Do you have to convert the parabola to new variables?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to include the transformation and the equation in MathJax. Please translate the rest so the image can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the question says the equation needs to be represented by the new variables x` and y`, the relationship between x,y and x`,y` is the matrix representation. The problem is I think the equation can be written as a quadratic form but I couldn`t find a way to do it. After that, I guess using the relationship and the quadratic form this question can be solved using matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the problem is to write the equation
$$
x^2+16xy + 14y^2 -30x-40y=0
$$
in terms of the new variables $\ x',y'\ $.  The equation,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
 + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix}\ ,
$$
gives you the new variables in terms of the old.  What you need to do is invert this equation to give you the old variables in terms of the new:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\left(
   \begin{pmatrix} x'\\ y' \end{pmatrix}
 - \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix}\right)
$$
and then substitute the expressions for the old variables in terms of the new into the quadratic equation. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much Ionza, this is definitely one of the ways to do it, but it is very exhausting, you mean the x`=2x+y and y`=3x+4y-5, then we can represent the x and y using these two equations. After that substitute back to the original equation then get the answer :)  Yes I tried before it is right but I think there is a better way

Comment: You can simplify the process a little by using matrix algebra.  The details are too long to include in a comment, so I've added them to my answer. I'm fairly sure there's nothing much else you can do to simplify the process further.

Comment: you are right Ionza, I tried another way( by adding a new variable z to construct a matrix) to solve that and it is also very exhausting lol. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer :) that is a great way!!

Comment: Well, I *thought* I had added the details of the matrix algebra, but they seem to have disappeared.  I've been having trouble with my WiFi connection, so they've apparently got lost on their way from my IPad  to my modem.  Since the method you've used is actually a bit neater than mine, anyway, I won't bother re-adding the details of the way I suggested doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers guys :) , I really appreciate that. By the way, I think I found an easier way to solve this problem. The parabola equation can be represented by a quadratic form if we multiply Z(Z=1) to -30x and -40y , then the equation is x^2+16xy+14y^2-30xz-40yz=0 (Z=1) and after that, this equation is a standard quadratic form. I will upload the photo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ush4p.jpg)